# Custom Widget doesn't display the same amount of choices

Tags: php, oop, widget, symfony-1.4

I try to create a customWidget with a special tablemethod to only display the pre selected choices of the user, this is the form :

```
$this->widgetSchema['Books_list'] = new MyWidgetFormThematicSelector(array(
            'multiple' => true,
            'model' => 'Books',
            'table_method' => array('method' => 'getOnlySelected', 'parameters' => array($this->getObject()->getId())),
            'expanded' => true,
        ));
```

this is the method getOnlySelected:

```
$q = Doctrine::getTable('BooksAuthors')
                ->createQuery('ba')
                ->select('ba.position,ba.name')
                ->leftJoin('ba.Books b')
                ->where('ba.BooksAuthors_id = ?', $id); 
 echo count($q); //return 4
 return $q;
```

this method return 4 elements which is normal then if i try to echo the values of the getChoices method from the widget I get only 1 in return !?

```
class MyWidgetFormThematicSelector extends sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceWithParams {

  public function configure($options = array(), $attributes = array()) 
  {
    parent::configure($options, $attributes);
  }


  public function getChoices() {

    $choices = parent::getChoices();
    echo count($choices);  // return 1
    return $choices;
  }

  public function render($name, $value = null, $attributes = array(), $errors = array()) {

    return parent::render($name, $value, $attributes, $errors);

  }

}
```

What's going on here ?

I create a similar widget in the same form where the probleme does not occurs, and it s quite the same code...

thx

Comment: Do you have the code for sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceWithParams? It's hard to tell without seeing how that class works. Do the parameters passed need to be in a key/value format e.g. Should the parameters passed be 'parameters' => array('id' => $this->getObject()->getId()))

Comment: here is the class, http://blog.squantin.fr/symfony-1-4-passer-des-parametres-sur-table_method-dans-un-sfwidgetformdoctrinechoice-4351, I think you have the right idea but instead of passing the key to sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceWithParams, I pass it directly from the form with key_method attribute.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. It looks as though this class has the capability to return 1 record or a collection of records as it sees fit. So I might step through it and see if that's what it has done to you in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by setting the attribute 'key_method' => 'myUniqueId', in the form where the widget is called...
Cause Ive got two primary keys in my table and the sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceWithParams widget use the one which was identic for all the results as the key for the array choices, so the size of the array was always one...By setting the other primary key as the main key of the getChoices method I get the correct result.